# GetAll method is not generated in VDM for custom OData Service

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We have a custom OData Service. The service url is as below:

```
https://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZAPI_TRANSFERPRICE_CONDTYPE_SRV/$metadata
```

It can return all the price conditions by accessing the following URL:

```
https://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZAPI_TRANSFERPRICE_CONDTYPE_SRV/TransferPriceCondition
```

After the service classes are generated based on the metadata of this service. The getAll method is not generated.

[image: all the methods generated for the service]

I am not sure if something is required in the OData service.

SAP Cloud SDK Version is 3.7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getAll()` method is disabled explicitly by setting `sap:addressable="false"` for the entity which is the case in the EDMX file you provided.

Comment: Thank you. It works. The metadata is generated by default. Just know there is a switch in it.

Answer (score 0):

generally speaking when using the OData client generator, there will/should be a getAll method if your service does not explicitly forbid it. Can you share the metadata (edmx) file of that service so that we can reproduce the issue? Otherwise it's impossible to guess where the problem comes from.

Comment: Thanks. I sent the metadata file to Marco for security purpose.